# Solving a C2039 error and a C3861 error using std::minmax_element

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm newer to C++.

I've written the following line in a test function inside a standard VS2019 test project:

```
auto minAndMaxYards = std::minmax_element(simResults.begin(), simResults.end());
```

It yields both C2039 and C3861 errors for the minmax_element function even though intellisense recognizes it as a member of std, and I can peek its definition.  I can't figure out what I'm missing.  I've included the algorithm file as well at the top of the test project.

Is there a project setting that I don't have right?

Full error text:

C2039   'minmax_element': is not a member of 'std'
C3861   'minmax_element': identifier not found

**Edit, including code in case it helps**

```
#include <algorithm>

#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "Playbook.h"
#include "PlaySim.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

std::string output;
using std::vector;

namespace FootballDynastyV20UnitTest
{
    TEST_CLASS(PlaybookIO)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(setAndGetPlayblookName)
        {
            Playbook testPlays;

            string testName = "testPlays";

            testPlays.setName(testName);
            string name = testPlays.getName();

            Assert::IsTrue(name == testName);

        }

        TEST_METHOD(addPlayIncrementsPlayNum)
        {
            Playbook testPlays;
            
            string playName = "Play1";
            int numDLine = 4;
            int numLB = 3;
            vector<int> playerPos = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19 };
            vector<int> playerStance = { 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3 };
            vector<int> playerBlitzGaps = { 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };


            testPlays.setName("testPlays");
            testPlays.addPlay(playName, numDLine, numLB, playerPos, playerStance, playerBlitzGaps);

            Assert::IsTrue(testPlays.getNumPlays() == 1);
        }

        TEST_METHOD(saveAndLoadPlayblook)
        {
            Playbook testPlays;
            Playbook testPlaysLoad;

            string playName = "Play1";
            int numDLine = 4;
            int numLB = 3;
            vector<int> playerPos = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19 };
            vector<int> playerStance = { 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3 };
            vector<int> playerBlitzGaps = { 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };


            testPlays.setName("testPlays");
            testPlays.addPlay(playName, numDLine, numLB, playerPos, playerStance, playerBlitzGaps);
            testPlays.save();

            testPlaysLoad.load(testPlays.getName());

            
            Assert::IsTrue(testPlays == testPlaysLoad);
        }
    };

    TEST_CLASS(PlaySimTesting)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(playSimReturnsYdsGainedBetweenNegative10And40)
        {
            PlaySim newPlay;
            int numSims = 2000;
            int lwrBound = -10;
            int uprBound = 40;
            vector<int> simResults;

            for (int i = 0; i < numSims; i++)
            {
                newPlay.Run();
                simResults.push_back(newPlay.GetYds());
            }
            
            auto minAndMaxYards = std::minmax_element(simResults.begin(), simResults.end());

            int actualMin = *minAndMaxYards.first;
            int actualMax = *minAndMaxYards.second;

            int yds = newPlay.GetYds();

            Assert::IsTrue((actualMin >= lwrBound) && (actualMax <= uprBound));

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Please include the full text of the error messages.  Most people don't have the numeric codes memorized, and the actual error message will include additional context besides.

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point, added.

Comment: You need to `#include <algorithm>` before using `std::minmax_element()`/

Comment: And show the `include` statements you have; `minmax_element` is in `<algorithm>`. Do you include that?

Comment: @DaveNewton
Yes, I did mention that, but '#include <algorithm>' is at the top of my file.

Comment: Edit the question to include a [mre] - all the code we need to recreate the problem.

Comment: Then you're using a C++ compiler/library that predates C++11. `std::minmax_element()` was introduced by C++11.   You either need to code up an alternative to get what you need, or update your compiler/library to C++11 or later.

Comment: @Peter VS2019 certainly supports C++11.

Comment: @Peter that's confusing to me.  I'm running it on VS2019 using ISO C++14, the latest Windows SDK, and v142 toolset.  I've also got another solution that uses the exact same code but seems to compile just fine and I can't find any differences in project settings.

Comment: @Eugene - Project settings, environment settings, etc can have an effect on that (or there's a broken installation).   I remember someone once who had both a VS 2019 installation and an older one on their machine (can't remember how they did that) and had strange interactions.   Alternatively, there is something in the OPs code (e.g. `<algorithm>` is included conditionally, and the condition isn't met) that causes a problem.

Comment: I added the code from the test project in case that helps, although there are multiple includes of other files from the main project and that would get lengthy to include everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `#include "pch.h"` to the top of the file. When using precompiled headers, the compiler ignores everything above this line. In your example, that would be `#include <algorithm>`, that's why `std::minmax_element` is not found.

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you!  Didn't realize that was the behavior, and wasn't thinking about the testing project using a precompiled header.